# SQL Function pagination - One to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, pagination, supabase-database

I am writing a Supabase Database function using SQL. I have 2 tables one is Product and Other is Inventory. One product can have multiple inventory entries so Product table does have one to many relationship with Inventory table.

I want to paginate this function and return 10 product record with their related inventories record. Here I am having issue with pagination. If first product record does have 4 inventory record, it count as 4 record not just one in pagination. How can I overcome this situation. Please help.

Below is my function code

```
create or replace function fetch_products(pageNumber int, pageSize int, cat text, subcat text, brand text, color text, size text, price text)
returns table (id int, productName text, quantity int, remainingQuantity int, color text, price text, size text, images text) as $$
  select pro."id", "productName", "quantity", "remainingQuantity", "color", "price", "size", "images"
  from product pro inner join inventory as inv 
  on pro.id = inv.product_id 
  where pro."categoryCode" = cat
  and (subCat IS NULL OR pro."subcategoryCode" in (subCat))
  and (brand IS NULL OR pro."brandCode" in (brand))
  and (color IS NULL OR inv."color" in (color))
  and (size IS NULL OR inv."size" in (size))
  and (price IS NULL OR inv."price" in (price))
  and pro."isActive" = true
  and inv."isActive" = true
  and inv."remainingQuantity" > 0
  offset (pageSize * pageNumber) rows fetch next pageSize rows only;
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: You need to use group by to make each row have a single produce. You can then use aggregate functions to get the list of inventories into a single array or whatever you please it to be! https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html